# my internet speed is showing 1.7mbps but the download speed is only 20kbps and under

Tags: router, internet

i am from lebanon and i am registered to 10mbps internet . my internet speed is showing 1.7mbps but the download speed is only 20kbps and under sometimes the internet speed shows 2.7mbps but the download speed still the same maximum 50kbps also i am using USB tethering from my phone to get internet to my PC. what is the problem ?

Comment: [related](https://superuser.com/a/1300684/172747)

Comment: Neither of these answers explain your situation. Start with the host operating system, router(if applicable), and phone/provider. Add as much information as you can, it will help you to **not** receive a **generic response.**

Answer (score 0):

Of course it always shows a higher download rate when you use e.g. fast.com. But when you download things, you download from the nearest mirror, which can be far away from you, so that is the explanation, why you get 20kbps or 50kbps. And if you use USB-Tethering, it also depends how much signal you can receive to your phone. Try at another place around your house, see how much signal you can get, and try downloading something else (e.g. testfiles) from the nearest mirror possible. You should then get higher download rates for sure, but you cannot get the maximum out of it, you never can get. That is why providers say you get e.g. **max.** 100MB/s in Download.

Comment: thanks for supporting me with this information i will try your e.g.

Comment: It might be the computer is using generic drivers to tether. He has this tagged as router, which makes it even more confusing. What ISP do you have that doesn't provide the advertised speeds? I wouldn't take that very kindly.

Answer (score 0):

Your location *might* have an influence on this.

Numerous country around you have [state-wide firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_censorship). 
While I could not find any evidence of the existence of one for Lebanon, this might be something relatively new.

Those system always have a negative impact on speed, sometime a large impact depending of the exact technical implementation.